# This keyword in Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just may get bombarded for asking such a silly question but it is more of a question that will help to make my understanding clear.

So in JavaScript,

```
  var firstName = "Peter",
    lastName = "Ally";

    function showFullName () {
    // "this" inside this function will have the value of the window object
    // because the showFullName () function is defined in the global scope, just like the firstName and lastName
    console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }

    var person = {
    firstName   :"Penelope",
    lastName    :"Barrymore",
    showFullName:function () {
    // "this" on the line below refers to the person object, because the showFullName function will be invoked by person object.
    console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }
    }

    showFullName (); // Peter Ally​
​
    // window is the object that all global variables and functions are defined on, hence:​
    window.showFullName (); // Peter Ally​
```

This is clear to me. Now inside an Angular controller, when we try to replicate this,

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
console.log("Before Controller",this);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    console.log(this);
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    this.myTestFunction = function(){
        return this;
    }

    console.log("In test function ",this.myTestFunction());
});
</script>
```

The `second` line still should log `window` right as the controller function is defined in the global scope (**I suppose**). `But in turn, it returns an Object. Why ?`

Also , Can I use `this.myTestFunction` without using a `ControllerAs` syntax. What is the difference between two?

`Why the last line also logs`object`(In myTestFunction) when I am just simply returning this from within`?

I am not sure about all of these. Could someone explain in simple terms?

```
Before Controller Window {stop: function, open: function, alert: function, confirm: function, prompt: function…}
VM2143 tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_module:5 Object {}
VM2408 tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_module:12 In test function  Object {myTestFunction: function}
```

Comment: controller function is not defined in global scope. Can clearly see it is an argument of function `angular.controller()`

Answer (score 1):

the reason why last console log show `object object` is that you try to concatenate object to a string. remove the string and just show the function response.

```
console.log(this.myTestFunction());
```

as for the 2nd question you can not access the `this.myTestFunction` in html without using the controller as function. without it, angular can only identify the scope functions in the controller.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
console.log("Before Controller",this);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    console.log(this);
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    this.myTestFunction = function(){
        return this;
    }

    console.log("In test function ",this.myTestFunction());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Still I have a doubt on second `console.log(this)`. Is not the controller function is defined within global scope? So, should it not display window instead of an object?

Comment: because once you create a controller angular create a scope for that function. so the controller act as a separate constructor. so inside the controller, we have new this and only the thing we declare inside the controller allocate as a property to this. in this case `myTestFunction` function

Answer (score 0):

> The second line still should log window right as the controller
>   function is defined in the global scope (I suppose). But in turn, it
>   returns an Object. Why ?

In AngularJs Controllers, Services, Factories etc, `this` keyword is definitely your controller/module itself. In facts, when a Module Constructor is called, `this` is the module itself. In few words, `this` on a Controller is an Object containing all of controller's functions and variables. If a Controller `MyController` is bound to a view `MyView.html` then only that precise view can access to `MyController`'s variables and functions.

> Also , Can I use this.myTestFunction without using a ControllerAs
>   syntax. What is the difference between two?

No, you can't use `this` without using `ControllerAs` syntax. Let's suppose you have

```
angular.module('myApp')
       .controller('MyController', MyController);

function MyController(){
   var vm = this;
   vm.hello = 'Hello There!';
}
```

And

```
<body ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl">
  <p>{{myCtrl.hello}}</p>
</body>
```

It would nicely render `Hello There!`.

> Why the last line also logsobject(In myTestFunction) when I am just simply returning this from within?

Simply because, as said before, `this` is an object containing all the variables and functions instantiated inside the controller itself.

**Extra**

You should prefer using `this` instead of `$scope` inside your controller. There are few reasons for that. One of them is that when you define a function using `this` then you know for sure that this particular function is accessible to a given view or to a given module. Take a look at [Angular Style Guide by John Papa on Controllers](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers).